# Search blank numeric value from a column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a numeric column having blank in DB table.
I'm trying this :

```
select top 10   
       CHQNO,
       ACCOUNT,
       SURNAME,
       OTHRNAME,
       CHQAMT,
       BANKNO,
       PYMTNO,
       GLACCTNO 
from   table1 
where  CHQAMT = ''
```

Note: CHQAMT column type is decimal

and getting error: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

How to resolve  this?

Comment: By blank do you mean having the NULL value?

Comment: No. In my opinion NULL is not Blank. Blank means a white space.

Comment: A numeric or decimal column can never have a 'blank space' value. It is either a valid numeric or decimal value or it can have no value at all which would be a NULL.

Comment: a decimal column can never ever have a white space

Answer (score 2):

If CHQAMT is numeric, you should check if it's NULL (blank = '' only for string)

```
select top 10 
       CHQNO,
       ACCOUNT,
       SURNAME,
       OTHRNAME,
       CHQAMT,
       BANKNO,
       PYMTNO,
       GLACCTNO 
from   table1 
where CHQAMT IS NULL;
```

Some simple tests:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 (NUM INT, STRING VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (1, '');
INSERT INTO TEST1 VALUES (0, 'Zero');

 SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE NUM IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
    NUM STRING
1   NULL    NULL
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE STRING IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
    NUM STRING
1   NULL    NULL
```

-----Next one (for datatype VARCHAR would have different result in Oracle, but this is not your case)

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE STRING = '';
```

Output:

```
    NUM STRING
1   1
```

And at last:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 WHERE CAST(NUM AS VARCHAR(10))= '';
```

Output (nothing): actually I think it has not any meaning.

Comment: is "NULL" same as "Blank"?

Comment: what do you mean by Blank ?

Comment: Absolutely NOT.  Null mean absence of a value.  Blank (for string data type) = '' (but is a value).

Comment: Blank = Nothing = may be a white space

Comment: a white space is not nothing. Null can be considered as nothing.

Comment: Without making repetions, you can try "NULL and blank" on Google to find a lot of resoureces.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a numeric column then the value can't be blank.  The reason you're getting the error message "`Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`" is that when you compare to '' it is trying to convert the string '' to a number to do the comparison.

If you're looking for null values you have to change your query to be:

```
select top 10   
       CHQNO,
       ACCOUNT,
       SURNAME,
       OTHRNAME,
       CHQAMT,
       BANKNO,
       PYMTNO,
       GLACCTNO 
from   table1 
where  CHQAMT is null
```

If you really are looking for a blank, which i suspect is not the case you'd need to change your query to be:

```
select top 10   
       CHQNO,
       ACCOUNT,
       SURNAME,
       OTHRNAME,
       CHQAMT,
       BANKNO,
       PYMTNO,
       GLACCTNO 
from   table1 
where  convert(varchar,CHQAMT) = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking like this...

```
select top 10   
           CHQNO,
           ACCOUNT,
           SURNAME,
           OTHRNAME,
           CHQAMT,
           BANKNO,
           PYMTNO,
           GLACCTNO 
    from   table1 
    where  ( CHQAMT is null OR CONVERT(varchar,CHQAMT) = '' OR CONVERT(int, CHQAMT) = 0 )
```